# How to send data from SpringBoot to flask

Tags: json, spring-boot, flask, resttemplate

I want to send data in json format to Flask in Spring Boot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWCne.png)

Currently Flask is ready to receive data to send from Spring Boot.

Comment: Please post the code as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

use webclient or rest template or u can use redis or kafka to publish data then the flask app consumes it

Answer (score 0):

As the first floor said, you can send an post request with json body